# How to remove line from input type color

Tags: css

I have an input type color.[Choose color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVZIo.png)

The problem is the line inside the input type. My code looks like this

```
.input-field-color{
  background-color : #000033 !important;
  color : #000033 !important;
  max-width: 90px;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline-style:none;
  border-color:transparent;
  border:0;
  outline:none;
}
```

And on the page.

```
<input type="color" name="chooseColor" id="chooseColor" class="form-control input-field-color" [(ngModel)]="chooseColor" #chooseColor="ngModel" required maxlength="15">
```

Comment: input::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not working.

Comment: It looks the same in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

to remove the line you just need to use following css code

```
input::-webkit-color-swatch { border: none; }
```